# Adobe ColdFusion 9 Pagination looping issue

Tags: for-loop, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

I am working on an application that is displaying pagination incorrectly. 
Here is the code:

```
  <cfif ...>
     <cfoutput><li class=""><a href="#FP#">First</a></li></cfoutput>
     <cfoutput><li class=""><a href="#link#">Previous</a></li></cfoutput>
  <cfelse>
  </cfif>

  <!--- Start Page Numbers --->
  <cfset totalPages = Ceiling(SmartGuideSearchRet.recordCount / perpage)>
  <cfset whichPage = round((url.start)/perPage + 1)>

  <cfloop index="a" from="1" to="#totalpages#"> //returns total pagination tabs
      <cfoutput>
      <cfset whichPage = round((url.start)/perPage + 1)>
      <cfif pagecount EQ whichPage>
         <li class="active" id="wp"><a href="?start=#pageLink#">#pagecount#</a></li>  
      <cfelse>
        <li id="wp"><a href="?start=#pageLink#">#pagecount#</a></li> 
      </cfif>
     </cfoutput>

     <cfset pageCount = pageCount + 1>
     <cfset pageLink = pageLink + perpage>
  </cfloop>
  <!--- End Page Number ---> 

  <cfif (url.start + perpage - 1) lt SmartGuideSearchRet.recordCount>
     <cfset link = cgi.script_name & "?start=" & (url.start + perpage)>
     <cfset LP = cgi.script_name & "?start=" & (SmartGuideSearchRet.recordCount)>

     <cfoutput><li><a href="#link#">Next</a></li></cfoutput>
     <cfoutput><li><a href="#LP#">Last</a></li></cfoutput>
  <cfelse>
  </cfif>
```

Here is the output on my application:

[image: incorrect pagination]

This is how I want my pagination to look like:

I want it to loop through the total pages but only show 10 pagination tabs at a time so from 1-10 then 10-20 20-30 30-40 etc... until the total number of pagination tabs is reached.

Here is an image of how the start should look like:

[image]

I am still new to Coldfusion but I just cannot think of the logic. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you please provide the code to process your previous and next button ?

Comment: sorry about that, updated

Comment: What troubleshooting have you thus far done? You demonstrate it doesn't work (good), but you don't say that you've tried anything to fix it? Have you at least checked all the values of the variables you're using have the values you expect? If it's looping too many times... think what might cause that to happen? Then *investigate*. Pare back your code to output something simple for each page (like just a `*`), Do you get the right number of stars? Revise code until you do. Now output the page number instead of the star. Are those numbers correct? If not... why not? [etc]

Comment: All the values of the pagination tabs work. The first image(actual output), the loop is doing what it is supposed to do (working perfectly) but I just want it to show 10 tabs at a time instead of all 300+ at once.

Comment: The second image all I did was replace #totalpages# in the cfloop index to 10 and that was my output, but the pagination tabs only go up to 10 which is expected since my to="10". So to my understanding I need to loop through all of the #totalpages# but then need to display 10 pagination tabs at a time which I am struggling with coming up with the code

Comment: How do you conclude it's "working perfectly" if it's not doing what you want? Surely part of "working perfectly" is...showing "ten tabs at a time [etc]"? And the question still stands: what have you actually done to try to solve this yourself> IE: "show your working"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using Nathan Strutz's Pagination CFC. It was written specifically for this purpose and comes with many options & features you haven't mentioned (including styling).

http://www.dopefly.com/projects/pagination/

Example integration (from the website):

```
<cfset pagination = createObject("component", "components.Pagination").init() />
<cfset pagination.setQueryToPaginate(myQuery) />
<cfset pagination.setBaseLink("/app/photolist.cfm?year=2007") />
<cfset pagination.setItemsPerPage(25) />
<cfset pagination.setUrlPageIndicator("page") />
<cfset pagination.setShowNumericLinks(true) />

<cfoutput>#pagination.getRenderedHTML()#</cfoutput>

<cfoutput query="myQuery" startrow="#pagination.getStartRow()#" maxrows="#pagination.getMaxRows()#">
<li>#id# - #name#</li>
</cfoutput>

<cfoutput>#pagination.getRenderedHTML()#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: I will take a look at this today.